# Use Sum in certain conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have say the following rows

```
Country Population
IE  30
IE  20
UK  15
DE  20
DE  10
UK  20
BE  5
```

So basically I want to net the values together only for IE and DE... the rest I just want the values

So this would sum them all ..

```
Select Country, Sum(Population) From CountryPopulation group by Country
```

and I can add a where clause to exclude all other countries except IE and DE... but I also want these in the result set but just not summed.

So the table above would look like this when summed

```
Country Population
IE  50         -- Summed
UK  15         -- Orginal Value
DE  30         -- Summed
UK  20         -- Orginal Value
BE  5          -- Orginal Value
```

Problem is I can’t get a sum if, or case to work as the query has to be aggregated by group by. Only other way I can thing on is to

Sum all the IE and DE and union it with the rest of the data..
Or
Maybe use a CTE

Is there a nice slick way of doing this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @t table (Country char(2), Population int)
insert into @t (Country, Population) values
('IE',30),
('IE',20),
('UK',15),
('DE',20),
('DE',10),
('UK',20),
('BE',5 )

; With Ordered as (
    select Country,Population,CASE
                                 WHEN Country in ('IE','DE') THEN 1
                                 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Country)
                               END as rn
    from @t
)
select Country,rn,SUM(Population)
from Ordered
group by Country,rn
```

Produces:

```
Country rn                   
------- -------------------- -----------
BE      1                    5
DE      1                    30
IE      1                    50
UK      6                    15
UK      7                    20
```

The trick is to just introduce a unique value for each row, except for the `IE` and `DE` rows that all get a `1`. If the source rows all, actually, already have such a unique value then the CTE can be simplified (or avoided, at the expense of having to place the `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` as well as the `SELECT`)

Answer (score 4):

```
Select Country, Sum(Population) 
From CountryPopulation 
group by case when Country in ('IE','DE')
              then 'IE_DE'
              else Country
         end
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to merge *together* the sums for `IE` and `DE` - I think they just want *one* row for `IE`, *one* row for `DE`, and then all other countries should have as many rows as they do in the source table.

Comment: thats correct Damien... I want to sum them by country and not combine them... but like the idea of a group in the case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `UNION ALL` and divide this query into two:

```
SELECT P.country, 
       P.population 
FROM  (SELECT country, 
              Population = Sum(population) 
       FROM   dbo.countrypopulation cp 
       WHERE  country IN ( 'IE', 'DE' ) 
       GROUP  BY country 

       UNION ALL 

       SELECT country, population 
       FROM   dbo.countrypopulation cp 
       WHERE  country NOT IN ( 'IE', 'DE' )
      ) P 
ORDER  BY P.population DESC
```

Even if this is not so concise it is readable and efficient.

<kbd>[**sql-fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a076/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: thanks Tim... yes this was the only one that I could come up with myself but I hate repeating SQL and wanted to see was there a more technical solution... thanks again